# Search for similar name in BASH

Tags: bash, awk

Thanks in advance for the help.  I am relatively new to BASH and have almost completed my first shell script, but have run into an issue that I cannot find the solution to due to its specificity.  Here is the problem:

I have a script that returns to following line from a text file to a variable:

**NAME="Ste e A. Johnson"**

I need to use that variable to find the following line within the text file and assign it to the same variable:

**Steven A. Johnson**

I believe that awk may be the proper function, but I have not been able to figure out how to make that work.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: `NAME=$(grep "${NAME# }" filename | head -n1)` if `Steven A. Johnson` exists by itself as a line in `filename`. To be more specific, you need to post the file you are searching for so we are not guessing at its format.

Comment: Steven A. Johnson does appear in its own line, but this still returns Ste e A. Johnson.  Thank you for the tip on posting the text file and I definitely will next time, unfortunately in this case more than half of the text file has information that must be kept confidential.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
name="Ste e A. Johnson"
name=${name// /.*}
found_name=$(grep -m1 -- "$name" filename)
```

This will replace all spaces in `name` with `.*`:

```
Ste e A. Johnson -> Ste.*e.*A..*Johnson
```

Which can then be used as an argument for grep. `-m1`, might be a GNU extension, gives first match only.

`.*` means match anything zero or more times, so `Ste.*e.*A..*Johnson` can match:

```
Steven A. Johnson
# But also
SteeA.Johnson
Steeeeeeeeven A. Johnson
This line will Ste also be matched, Ah I understand Johnson
...
```

Actually the `.` in `A.` should be escaped to match only a literal `.`:

```
name="Ste e A. Johnson"
name=${name//./\\.}
name=${name// /.*}
printf "%s\n" "$name"
Ste.*e.*A\..*Johnson
#        ^ Now the . is literal
```